# Fill a list in python with values from a smaller list by indexes contained in another list with the same size?

Tags: python, list, nonetype

I have a list full of indexes named g_index, I have another list of the same size,named fill_list, full of values. I also have another list, P1, that is longer than g_index and fill_list. I want to create a  new list of size, P1, that has the value of fill_list in the indexes of g_index, with the rest of the values being therefore, None. Note that the items in fill_list will fill the indexes in g index in a sequential order. This means that the first item of fill_list will go on index 3 of the new list ( I call it finaList in the code) and so on and so forth. The size of the list created should be the size of P1, with the values of fill_list in indexes denoted by g_index.
Here is what I have:

```
g_index=[3,6,2,83,7,100,5,1]
fill_list=["lk",3,6,9,"gh",4,7,34]
finalList=[]
for index in range(len(P1)):
   for j in range(len(g_index)):
      if index== g_index[j]:
         finalList.append(fill_list)
print finalist
```

In my code, the final list just keeps appending itself with values, which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
final_list = []

for i in range(len(P1)):
    if i in g_index:
        final_list.append(fill_list)
    else:
        final_list.append(None)
```

In the above example, `whatever` could be the whole final_list, or an item from fill_list.

Comment: I cannot do that because the values that I am appending to the final list comes from a smaller  than P1 so I get an index out of range error.

Comment: in your example , is whatever a list or is it a single item? whatever should be  fill_List[i]. If I do that it is a index out of range error.

Comment: it doesn't matter, whichever you want. You could append a whole list or just an item

Comment: It can be fill_list(the whole list) if you want it to be... that's how you have it in your example I think

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list with None (or anything else) and then map the values like this:

```
g_index=[3,6,2,83,7,100,5,1]
fill_list=["lk",3,6,9,"gh",4,7,34]
p1 = [None] * (max(g_index) + 1)
for k, v in enumerate(g_index):
    p1[v] = fill_list[k]
print(p1)
```